# Search by tag id using many to many relationship mysql

Tags: mysql

Ok, so this is my problem:
I have tags system that can be attributed to users and companies. I want to extract the companies that match with user tags.

Schema is this:

Table Tags:

```
| id | tag_name |
| 1  |   tag 1  |
| 2  |   tag 2  |
| 3  |   tag 3  |
```

Table Users:

```
| id | user_name |
| 1  |   user1   |
| 2  |   user2   |
```

Table Users Tags:

```
| id | id_user | id_tag |
| 1  |    1    |   1    |
| 2  |    1    |   3    |
```

Table Companies:

```
| id | company_name |
| 1  |  company 1   |
| 2  |  company 2   |
```

Table Companies Tags:

```
| id | id_user | id_company | id_tag |
| 1  |    1    |      1     |   1    |
| 2  |    1    |      1     |   3    |
```

both tags: tag1 and tag3 are present on user1 and company 1. How do i extract companies that match with user tags?

Thanks

Comment: Just to check... `Table Tags`, row 3, id should be 3? And does `Table Companies Tags` really have id_user?

Comment: @CodeConfident it doesn't matter, there can be many tags inside table tags. This is under a login system, so every user that is logged in may have different tags.

Comment: So what have you tried, what error did you get? Or you just want us to do the work?

Comment: @nacho i don't know how to use many to many relationship mysql queries, if someone can explain it to me how to do it will be great

Comment: using JOINS, just the same as other tables. If you have tables A, B, C, where B represents the link between A and C (i.e. holds the many to many data) then normally you need a join from A to B, and another join from B to C. e.g. In your case join from Tags -> UsersTags, and join from UsersTags -> Users if you need data from Users as well. And to involve companies you can go from Tags (already in your query) -> CompaniesTags, and from there CompaniesTags -> Companies if necessary as well. Try that and post your SQL here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically start at one end and keep joining: User--UserTag--CompanyTag--Company:

```
SELECT u.id, c.id
FROM       Users u
INNER JOIN UsersTags ut        ON u.id = ut.id_user
INNER JOIN CompaniesTags ct    ON ct.id_tag = ut.id_tag
INNER JOIN Companies c         ON ct.id_company = c.id
GROUP BY u.id, c.id
```

...gives pairs of (user, company) that share at least one tag.

Inner join removes rows that don't have data on both sides of the join.
Group by remove duplicates arising from multiple tags linking the same User-Company.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it for your result as i expected.

```
    SELECT 
     u.id,
     c.id ,
     GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name SEPARATOR '<br/>') AS Tags
    FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN UsersTags ut ON(u.id = ut.id_user)
    INNER JOIN CompaniesTags ct ON (ct.id_tag = ut.id_tag)
    INNER JOIN Companies c ON (ct.id_company = c.id)
    INNER JOIN Tags t ON (t.id = ct.id_tag)
    GROUP BY u.id, c.id
```